# How to divide grid system in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image][image]

I want to divide grid system to 2 in medium screen and 1 in small screen
as in photo

Comment: "and 1 in small screen", what do you mean by that?

Comment: `col-md-6` to your 2  `div` will work, if I understand that's what you are expecting.

Comment: https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/aYgrwM

Comment: Please post the code as well so we can play with it and eventually fix it. :)

Comment: `col-md-6` to both of them will solve your problem

Comment: `col-md-6 col-sm-12`

Comment: the problem is still there

Comment: Provide more details of your requirement in your question, and also post your code rather than a screenshot. Will be easy for us

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet. 
Documentation: 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Asset number">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```